# Converting number to words in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

How can you convert a number to its written-equivalent in a formula?

For example, `10000` is converted to `Ten Thousand`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want to use the `ToWords()` and `ProperCase()` functions.

```
//{@Convert}
// returns Ten Thousand
ProperCase( ToWords(10000, 0) )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//{@Convert}
// returns Ten Thousand
ProperCase( ToWords(20,25000, 0) )
```

This show two hundred and twenty five thousand only.

Answer (score 2):

If you need in proper Indian formats like **Four lakhs Twenty Three Thousand...**etc, then follow the link https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/2030967. Refer comment by Balakumar Viswanathan. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbervar x:= int({numberfield});
numbervar y:= {numberfield}-x);
if(y>0)then
propercase("AED "+ ToWords((x),0)+" and"+ToWords((y*100),0)+" Fils Only")
else
propercase("AED "+ToWords((x),0)+" Only");
```

Comment: Provide explanation to your answer